# Excel VBA write to active cell

Tags: excel, vba

This should be so simple. All I want is for when a user clicks in a cell, say any cell in column B, then a concatenation of ...

text string "Update: "
Date/time
Their userID (Application.UserName)

I know I need something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
            ActiveCell.Select Environ("UserName")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

... gets written to that cell. E.g.  Update: Jane Smith 1/1/2015 00:00

Hope someone can help :-)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For any cell in column B, it would be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
           Target.Value = Target.Value & " Update: " & Environ("username") & " " & Now
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much it works just as I asked. I have just realised I need it to append the text to the cell, not overwrite if there is already text there.

Comment: To append instead of overwrite, change the central line of code to this: Target.Value = Target.Value & "Update: " & Environ("username") & " " & Now